# Cheating traversal

Tags: view, plone, traversal, zope

I'm developing a plone4 site on which every user have a sortable inventory of items. The ATFolder's folder_content view is ideal for this. The only problem is that instead of an URL like this:

```
/site/user/inventory
```

or this

```
/site/inventory/user
```

the url should be:

```
/site/inventory
```

I've thought in several solution, but each one have its own doubts.

- Make the inventory content dynamic, depending on the authenticated user. I don't even know if this is possible on plone.
- Somehow to cheat the transversal mechanism, so /site/inventory render /site/inventory/user.
- Change the context before rendering the view. Again, don't know if possible.
- Make inventory a subclass of ATCTContent, store the inventory data as annotation on the user and develop the ordering code all by myself. This is the option I'm trying to avoid.

What would you do?

Thanks.

Comment: How should that be possible especially when inventories of users may have identical ids for inventory items? There is no way in dealing with ID clashes here.  Of course you are free to rewrite site URLs using rewrite rules according to your needs. However this won't solve your problems with identical IDs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it'll be easy to define a `inventory` view that then uses the Authenticated User to render it's contents, which could be a simple delegation to an ordered folder that is stored at /site/users/user/folder.

The one thing that you have to remember is that user authentication happens after traversal. This means that when a view is instantiated (it's `__init__` method is called) there is no user determined yet because that happens during traversal. Look up your user in the view `__call__` or from it's template instead.

Answer (score 3):

Having folder contents show contents that are not the contents of the folder is crraaaaAAAAzytalk. :) Don't do it. Either have a folder per user ( /inventory/user ) or make a custom view called inventory.html. You can make /inventory sho /inventory user but that is one step towards trying to make Plone to non-ploneish things, and that way lies a world of pain.

I don't know why you couldn't just call it /inventory/user? Seems easy enough. Then stick an action in the user viewlet, by the dashboard link, and your done! :-)

Plone is a content management system. Use it for that, as it's supposed to be used, and you'll be happy. Trying to force it to do things it doesn't want is like trying to build a sportscar out of a art deco sculpture. It might end up looking awesome, but it won't run very well. :-)

Comment: Yes, I know I'm fighting plone and that's not a good thing. But requirements are requirements.